# copy binaries from /sourcedir and its subdirs to /destdir

Tags: bash, binaries

Copy all binaries from /sourcedir to /destdir.  Basically, all files with: no extension, and all files with *.a, *.so, *.ko, exclude from copy: *.c, *.h files. Copy files from all subdirs except the sub-directory named "excludeDir".

I have tried the following from bash:

```
find /my/sourcedir/ -mindepth 2 -type f -not -iname "excludeDir" -or "*.c" -or "*.h" -or "makefile" -print -exec cp {} /my/destdir \;
```

bash yields the following error:

> find: paths must precede expression: `*.c'

The command does not throw an error until attempting to exclude files/sub-directory.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Not clear, see [mcve]

Comment: ANSWERED -   https://superuser.com/questions/1507449/copy-binaries-from-sourcedir-and-its-subdirs-to-destdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find expect condition on the file name to follow `-name pattern`. This will be needed for the '*.c', '*.h' and 'Makefile' terms. (formatting for readability only, keep everything on one line).

```
find /my/sourcedir/ -mindepth 2 -type f -not '(' -iname "excludeDir"
    -or -name '*.c'
    -or -name '*.h'
    -or -name "makefile" ')' -print -exec cp {} /my/destdir \;
```

Comment: Command-line tool usage (for tools that aren't software-development-specific) isn't generally topical on SO anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, that was close enough.  This is what worked. `code` find /my/sourcedir/ -mindepth 2 -type f -not \( -iname "excludeDir" -or -iname '*.c' -or -iname '*.h' -or -iname '.ssh' -or -iname "Makefile" \) -exec cp {} /my/destdir \;